# Security in php session cookies

Tags: php, security, authentication, session-cookies

I am trying to understand security when it comes to session cookies in php. I've been reading a lot about it, but I still lack the specifics. I need the basics, someone to show examples.

For example: Do I place `session_regenerate_id()` before every session cookie? What more shall I think about. I am asking about specifics in code - examples if possible.

Thank you very much.

I am using 4 session cookies after logging in.

```
SESSION "site_logged_in" = true
SESSION "site_user_nr" = the number of the user to access user_table_nr
SESSION "site_user_id" = the user's id to use when changing data in tables
SESSION "site_user_name" = the name of the user to display on page
```

When I check if the user has access, I check if all 4 cookies are set, and if `site_logged_in` is set to true.

Are there better ways? Do I have the completely wrong idea about this? Can users easily be hacked?

Comment: You are actually using **one** cookie, no matter how many session *variables* you choose to use. I suggest reading a bit on [PHP session handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) and possibly also on HTTP cookies.

Comment: For a start, combine all the variables into 1 and separate with a colon. so `true:1:1:thomas`. Then use `list($site_logged_in,$site_user_nr...) = explode(SESSION_COOKIE_HERE);`.

Comment: Ben Carey: Would you care to write the whole code for what you just said?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest Ben's advice, it's a horribly inefficient way to handle what $_SESSION already provides.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you need to have only one session in your website. When you call session_start() session is being created on server and user automatically gets session cookie. Think like session is a some sort of container that placed on the server, you can put whatever you want in that container. However session cookie is just a key to access that container on the server.

It means that you can safely put some data in the $_SESSION and only the user that have cookie with matching session id can read it.

About users being hacked. Yes they can be hacked as long as you don't use HTTPS connection, because cookies and all other data is being transferred in clear text, so if someone intercept users cookie he can access the data stored in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Always use a security token for logging users. This security token could be generated by using [`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php). After logging users in, change the security token periodically until they log out. Also keep the server backup of all the session variables including the security token (in a database). This would also help you to track user login history.

One more personal suggestion: Never use any data from the database as session variables without encrypting it with any of the hashing functions or functions like `crypt()`.

Comment: Thanks! But that would require more traffic to the database? Like every time the user does something, I change the security token. Maybe that's not a problem though?

Comment: Yes that would create traffic. But you don't have to change the security token for small actions like navigation, etc. You could change it just before major actions like password update, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The session information is stored server-side. What you should check is that they're logged in, and that they exists/can log in (in case of deletions/bans).

As you're checking they exist/can log in, you can pull the other information from the database such as name, nr and so on. All you really need is a key called 'logged_in_user' or something that stores the ID of the logged in user. As Alex Amiryan said, the cookie can be copied, so you might also want to store the IP address of the last accessing view in the session, so you can try to ensure security.

Comment: But no one can find out the name of the cookie, right? That it is called "logged_in"?

Comment: And I would constantly have to get the user's data from the database, instead of having it in the session cookie. But maybe that is the way to do it?

Comment: The session keys ($_SEESION['site_logged_in'] for example) are not visible outside of the server. The cookie contains a unique key that refers to the session data. session data does not leave the server unless you cause it to.

Yes, you'd have to keep getting the user from the data, but that is the way to do it unless you find another method of checking for the existence of the user.

Comment: Can I set HttpOnly to a seesion cookie? How would one do that?